# update PATH variable in .bashrc using sed

Tags: sed, path

I've been trying to update my PATH variable permanently by putting it in my .bashrc file. However, I don't want to just append it to the file, but rather replace the current PATH=........ with the PATH variable I have for the session.
Here's what I have so far:

```
sed 's/^PATH=.*/${PATH=$PATH}/' .bashrc > .bashrc
```

This is a hodpodge of commands I've seen on the web, and when I run this, the .bashrc PATH line is overwritten with nothing. I would appreciate a solution using sed, because I want to add to the knowledge of sed I've gained in the last hour, rather than abadoning my efforts to awk or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing: don't write to a file you're reading from, you're likely to end up erasing it. Use the inplace-edit feature (`-i`) instead.

Next, inside hard quotes (`'`), variable substitution doesn't operate, so you'll need to do something else to get the expanded `$PATH` substituted in there.

Lastly, `$PATH` is very likely to contain `/` characters, which would break the substitution syntax for `sed`, so you'll need to use another separator.

Assuming your paths never contain `;`s, try (after having backed-up your current file of course):

```sh
sed -i 's;^PATH=.*;PATH='"$PATH"';' .bashrc
```

The match part of the substitution means: match a string that starts with (`^`) the string `PATH=` and followed by any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`). I.e. it will match lines that start with `PATH=` completely, but not lines that have `PATH=` somewhere in the middle. The `.*` is important because you want to replace the whole line (try without it to see what happens).

The quoting to get `$PATH` substituted inside the replacement is necessary to account for cases where `$PATH` would contain whitespace characters.

#### Demo:

```sh
$ foo=bar
$ echo hello | sed -e 's/hello/$foo/'
$foo
```

Env. vars are not substituted inside hard quotes. So you get a literal `$foo` there. Now let the shell expand it by bringing it out of the hard quotes:

```sh
$ foo=bar
$ echo hello | sed -e 's/hello/'$foo'/'
bar
```

Ok! But this isn't safe:

```sh
$ foo="bar baz"
$ echo hello | sed -e 's/hello/'$foo'/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command
```

`sed` received two arguments after `-e` above: `s/hello/bar` and `baz/`, separately. Not good. To fix that, you need a bit more quotes:

```sh
$ foo="bar baz"
$ echo hello | sed -e 's/hello/'"$foo"'/'
bar baz
```

Putting an environment variable inside `"` quotes is something you should pretty  much always do when you're passing it as an argument to something else, otherwise (assuming `$IFS` hasn't been changed) it will get split on whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly like it was planned! If you don't mind, I have some questions about the syntax: 1. Why is the ^ necessary?                              2. Why must there be ' and " around $PATH?

Comment: @Zchpyvr: added a few explanations & examples. Tell me if that doesn't clear it up.

Comment: That was really helpful, I understand the need for that syntax now! Your edit is a great explanation, and I want to thank you for taking time to explain it to me :)

Comment: Does this treat the case when the environment variable (e.g. ` $PYTHONPATH` ) is not present in ` .bachrc` , but should be defined?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś: no this won't add lines to the file

Comment: Is there a way to modify this snippet, so that it adds the line if not found in the file?